# as/the way that

Tags: relative-clauses

1. In the context of plants, to sprout is to begin to develop leaves and other parts, **as** we can see here happening with this plant.

Can we paraphrase it like this:

In the context of plants, to sprout is to begin to develop leaves and other parts, **the way that** we can see here **[ ]** happening with this plant.

Answer (score 1):

*As we can see* is a fixed expression meaning *"evidently, obviously, clearly, as presented."*

It's not recommended to break such expressions down into parts and try finding synonyms for them.

By doing so, the meaning will probably mislead you.

Comment: In sentence (1) in the OP, how is "**happening with this plant**" connected with "**as we can see here**"? Or is there not any connection between them, ie, they are independent of each other? Because "**happening with this plant**" seems to me to be lacking a subject in that sentence.

Comment: @Mr. X *", which is [apparently] happening with this plant."* would be the most common choice here. Apparently is the meaning of "as we can see" - more synonyms are provided in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

As we can see here .... is happening with this plant.
"The way that" I do not believe makes much sense in this kind of sentence.